# Check Date renge found in between mysql startdate enddate column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, .net, database

In My database has two column and data like below

```
   StartDate      Enddate
   2015-10-01     2015-10-30
   2015-10-15     2015-11-15
   2015-09-15     2015-10-15
```

if i search with startdat : 2015-10-16 Enddate : 2015-10-20 than want all above result,Please help me

My query as below

```
Select * from campaign as c LEFT JOIN campaign_team as t ON c.campaign_id=t.campaign_id where t.user_id
  ='6' and 
(campaign_sdate BETWEEN '2015-10-16' AND '2015-10-20' or campaign_edate BETWEEN '2015-10-16' AND '2015-10-20'
 or ( campaign_sdate <= 2015-10-16 and campaign_edate >= 2015-10-20 ) );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are wanting the start date to be 2015-10-16 and end date to be 2015-10-20 then how would the third record appear in your results?

Answer (score 0):

You have written opposite condition

```
or ( campaign_sdate >= 2015-10-16 and campaign_edate <= 2015-10-20 ) );
```

remove `BETWEEN` when you are using this.

Final query,

```
Select * from campaign as c LEFT JOIN campaign_team as t ON c.campaign_id=t.campaign_id where t.user_id
='6' or ( campaign_sdate >= 2015-10-16 and campaign_edate <= 2015-10-20 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
  Select * from campaign as c LEFT JOIN campaign_team as t ON c.campaign_id=t.campaign_id where t.user_id ='6' and campaign_sdate >= 2015-10-16 and campaign_edate <= 2015-10-20;
```

I flipped the greater than and less than sign.

Answer (score 0):

Does wrapping the and query within parenthesis so the query evaluates these separately to the OR portion work:

```
Select * 
from campaign as c LEFT JOIN campaign_team as t ON c.campaign_id=t.campaign_id where t.user_id  ='6' 
                    and (
                          (campaign_sdate BETWEEN '2015-10-16' AND '2015-10-20' 
                          or campaign_edate BETWEEN '2015-10-16' AND '2015-10-20')

                    or ( campaign_sdate <= '2015-10-16' and campaign_edate >= '2015-10-20' ) );
```

[Here is a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78ea/7/0) showing my query

EDIT: found missing '' around the last two date conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Two periods overlap if the 1st ends after the 2nd started and the 1st start before the 2nd ends:

```
Select * 
from campaign as c 
JOIN campaign_team as t 
ON c.campaign_id=t.campaign_id 
where t.user_id  ='6' 
    and campaign_sdate <= '2015-10-20'
    AND campaign_edate >= '2015-10-16'
```

I removed the LEFT JOIN because the `where t.user_id  ='6'` changes the result to an inner join anyway